# Differentiate () = [expcos] /(sin)

Tags: derivatives

My working is by using the quotient rule .

$U'=-\sin x(e^{\cos x})$

$V'= \cos x$

$\frac {[U’ V - V' U]}{V^2} = \frac {(-\sin x -\cos x)(e^{\cos x})}{(\sin x)}$

is my answer right ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer to your question

$$g(x)= \frac{e^x \cos x}{\sin x}$$
$$g'(x) = \frac{( (e^x \cos x)' \cdot \sin x) - (\sin x)' \cdot (e^x \cos x)}{\sin^2 x}$$ 
Here $( \: )'$ denote the derivatives.

The derivative of $(e^x \cos x)$ can be found using the product rule.

Comment: $g(x)=\dfrac{e^{\cos x}}{\sin x}$, I think.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{-\sin{x}e^{\cos{x}}\cdot\sin{x}-e^{\cos{x}}\cos{x}}{\sin^2x}=-\frac{e^{\cos{x}}(\sin^2x+\cos{x})}{\sin^2x}$$

Comment: because i am getting confused on whether we could factorise out the (sinx)^2 . as in from the numerator and denominator . that is how i got my answer

Comment: @Joseph Matt I think you can not make this because there is "$+$" between $\sin^2x$ and $\cos{x}$. In another words $\frac{\sin^2x+\cos{x}}{\sin^2x}\neq\frac{\sin{x}+\cos{x}}{\sin{x}}$.

Answer (score 0):

First using the quotient rule:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{\text{f}\left(x\right)}{\text{g}\left(x\right)}\right)=\frac{\text{f}\space'\left(x\right)\cdot\text{g}\left(x\right)-\text{f}\left(x\right)\cdot\text{g}\space'\left(x\right)}{\text{g}^2\left(x\right)}\tag1$$

So, we get:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{\exp\left(\cos\left(x\right)\right)}{\sin\left(x\right)}\right)=\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\exp\left(\cos\left(x\right)\right)\right)\cdot\sin\left(x\right)-\exp\left(\cos\left(x\right)\right)\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)}{\sin^2\left(x\right)}\tag2$$

Now, we know that:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)=\cos\left(x\right)\tag3$$

And:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\text{y}\left(\text{z}\left(x\right)\right)\right)=\text{z}\space'\left(x\right)\cdot\text{y}\space'\left(\text{z}\left(x\right)\right)\tag4$$

So:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\exp\left(\cos\left(x\right)\right)\right)=-\sin\left(x\right)\exp\left(\cos\left(x\right)\right)\tag5$$

So, we get:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{\exp\left(\cos\left(x\right)\right)}{\sin\left(x\right)}\right)=\frac{-\sin\left(x\right)\exp\left(\cos\left(x\right)\right)\cdot\sin\left(x\right)-\exp\left(\cos\left(x\right)\right)\cdot\cos\left(x\right)}{\sin^2\left(x\right)}\tag6$$